# How do I change the colour of a specific branch within QTreeView?

Tags: python, qt

I have a QTreeView, and I've figured out how to set its style by using setStyleSheet in my main class:

```
self.view.setStyleSheet("""
    QTreeView::item {
        margin: 2px;
    }
""")
```

That will style the entire QTreeView. But I want certain items in the tree to be bolded. When I create the branches (using `[the parent widget].appendRow("the name of the item")`), is there a way to 'tag' or isolate specific items so it can be styled the same way? I think the answer has something to do with the 'AccessibleName' or 'ObjectName' properties, but I'm having trouble finding documentation on it.

**Update**: This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from future_builtins import *

import os, sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

path_to_media = '/Volumes/show/vfx/webisodes/%d1%/seq/%d2%/%d3%/renders/2d/comp/'

class FileTree(QTreeView):
    """Main file tree element"""
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space or event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            index = self.selectedIndexes()[0]
            crawler = index.model().itemFromIndex(index)
            if crawler.uri:
                print("launching", crawler.uri)
                p = os.popen(('open -a "RV.app" "'+ crawler.uri) +'"', "r")
        QTreeView.keyPressEvent(self, event)

class Branch(QStandardItem):
    """Branch element"""
    def __init__(self, label, uri = None, tag = None):
        QStandardItem.__init__(self, label)
        self.uri = uri

class AppForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(AppForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.view = FileTree()
        self.view.setStyleSheet("""
            QTreeView::item {
                margin: 2px;
            }
        """)
        self.view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.Grow()
        # self.view.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def Grow(self):
        """Populates FileTree (using BuildBranch())"""
        global path_to_media
        self.path = {}
        self.path['source'] = path_to_media
        self.path['parts'] = []
        self.path['depth'] = 0
        self.path['crawl'] = {}
        for i in self.path['source'].split('%'):
            if i[0] == "d" and i[1].isdigit():
                self.path['depth'] += 1
            else:
                self.path['parts'].append(i)
        self.BuildBranch(self.path['parts'], self.path['depth'], parentWidget = self.model.invisibleRootItem())

    def BuildBranch(self, parts, depth, uri = '', count = 0, parent = '', parentWidget = ''):
        """Recursively crawls folder structure and adds appropriate branches"""
        if not uri: uri = parts[0]
        else: uri += parent + parts[count]
        try:
            if os.listdir(uri):
                for i in os.listdir(uri):
                    if i[0] != '.':
                        if count != depth:
                            if os.path.isdir(uri):
                                thisWidget = Branch(i)
                                parentWidget.appendRow(thisWidget)
                                self.BuildBranch(parts, depth, uri, count + 1, i, parentWidget = thisWidget)
                            else:
                                thisWidget = Branch(i)
                                parentWidget.appendRow(thisWidget)
                        elif count == depth:
                            thisWidget = Branch(i, uri + i, 'media')
                            parentWidget.appendRow(thisWidget)
            else:
                print("nothing here; nuking " + parent)
                # Need to add code to nuke unused branch
        except OSError:
            print("Folder structure error... nuking the branch")
            # Need to add code to nuke unused branch

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = AppForm()
    form.resize(800, 600)
    form.setWindowTitle('Qt Dailies')
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Update 2:** Okay, I modified my Branch class so that if 'bold' is passed to it, it makes the branch bold (in theory)...

```
class Branch(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, label, uri = None, tag = None):
        QStandardItem.__init__(self, label)
        self.uri = uri
        if tag == 'bold':
            self.setData(self.createBoldFont(), Qt.FontRole)
    def createBoldFont(self):
        if self.font: return self.font
        self.font = QFont()
        self.font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
        return self.font
```

... but while the code runs, nothing seems to happen. What am I still not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt's model-view architecture allows for data that describes the [different roles](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) being performed.  For example, there is a role for editing data, displaying data, etc. You're interested in the font role (i.e. `Qt::FontRole`) as the [font](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qfont.html) has a [weight](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qfont.html#Weight-enum) enum of which bold is one value.

When you build your branches you first need to identify which items should be bolded. I'll assume you have a method like such that can identify whether or not they should be bold:

```
def should_be_bolded(self, item):
    return 1 # your condition checks
```

Now just set the weight on the font and set the font role of the item using its [setData](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qstandarditem.html#setData) method:

```
def BuildBranch(...):
    thisWidget = Branch(i)
    if self.should_be_bolded(thisWidget):
        thisWidget.setData(self.createBoldFont(), Qt.FontRole)

def createFont(self):
    if self.font: return self.font
    self.font = QFont()
    self.font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
    return self.font
```

But wait... you already have a subclass of QtandardItem, so you can use that:

```
class Branch(QStandardItem):
    """Branch element"""
    def __init__(self, label, uri = None, tag = None):
        QStandardItem.__init__(self, label)
        self.uri = uri
        if self.should_be_bolded():
            self.bold_myself()
```

You'll have to fix the `should_be_bolded` and `bold_myself` methods, cleaning up accordingly, but hopefully you get the point.

Stephen [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097881/how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-a-specific-branch-within-qtreeview/7098762#7098762) that you can also subclass one of the `QAbstractItemModel`s, like the `QStandardItemModel` you're using, and return a specific `Qt.FontRole`. His way makes that knowledge implicit in the model. Decide where that knowledge best belongs and place it in the most appropriate place, whether it's in the item, the  tree-creation algorithm, the model, or even a view model.

Comment: Okay, I thought I understood, but when I rewrote my Branch class to have a bold FontRole, nothing happened. I added the new class code to my initial post.

Comment: Assuming you're passing the bold tag in, it looks right. I'll try to test it out and get back to you.

Comment: I got it working -- for some reason, "if self.font: return self.font" was always firing, even before self.font had been created, so the font was never bolding. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your model's `data()` method you can add code to set the font depending on the content of the item.  For example, if you wanted to bold everything in one particular row,

```
def data(self, index, role):

    if role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
       if index.row() == 1:
           boldFont = QtGui.QFont()
           boldFont.setBold(True)
           return boldFont
```

You just need a way to retrieve the name of your branch when given an index for it.  That depends on the implementation of your tree model.

The Qt Model/View [tutorial](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/modelview.html) has a good example, although it's in C++.  Look at section 2.2 (Extending the Read Only Example with Roles).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by the `data()` method -- I've only been trying to use QT for a few days, so this is all pretty confusing for me (and my brain is having a lot of trouble trying to make sense of the C++ examples). I added my code-in-progress to my initial post.

Comment: @Stephen - He's not using a custom model at this point, so a bit further explanation would probably be helpful.